# number of dates in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript code

```
var dayarray = eval(data);
console.debug(dayarray);
```

it returns me following output

```
[
Object { Date=0.9090909090909091, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.8333333333333334, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.7692307692307693, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.7142857142857143, Amount=3430.7692307692305},
Object { Date=0.6666666666666666, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.625, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.5882352941176471, Amount=699.9999999999999},
Object { Date=0.5555555555555556, Amount=699.9999999999999}
]
```

I want to know the number of dates.

Comment: Great! ...so where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by *number of dates*?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do. Can you provide an example of input and output or explain it a little further?

Comment: @DavidThomas i tried console.debug(dayarray.Date.length). didn't work.

Comment: @MunimAbdulcount of dates in array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the length of the array ? `dayarray.length`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to know the number of objects with a 'Date' property?

```
dayarray.reduce(function(accum, elem) { 
    return accum + ('Date' in elem);
}, 0);
```